# ERROR 000539: Invalid Field !FULLNAME

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, error-000539

I am very new to Python and my first attempt hasn't gone too well.  I'm trying to overwrite a field that is a spatial join of a couple of features in order to, in the end, generate a beginning and ending street intersections listing.

Here is a link to my table.  The field I'm trying to overwrite is the `IntersectionList` field.

[image]

As you can see, the `IntersectionList` has the `SECONDARYN` field names included due to the spatial join. All I need now, are those streets that are not in the `SECONDARYN` field in order to create a beginning/ending street listing.

Here is a visual example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image]

This is the code I tried to use via the *Calculate Field* tool:

```
fixUpIntersections(!IntersectionList!, !FULLNAME!)


def fixUpIntersections(listAsString, streetname):
names = listAsString.split(" & ")
uniqueNames = list(set(names))
if len(uniqueNames) == 1:
    return uniqueNames[0]
    uniqueNames.remove(streetname)
return ' & '.join(sorted(uniqueNames))
```

I thought with the error I received, it meant that maybe I should `!FULLNAME!` to `!SECONDARYN!`, in order to get rid of those streets in the `IntersectionList` but when I tried that, it just deleted all data in the `IntersectionList`. Running the tool with the code exactly as shows above without changing `!FULLNAME!`, it resulted in the following error: `ERROR 000539: Invalid field FULLNAME`

[image]

I've dug around the site here but haven't been able to figure out my problem. I have a long way to go to learn Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing that I would check is whether your feature class has a field called `FULLNAME`.

The error message that you are receiving suggests that it does not.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought about last night. If I'm trying to remove the names that match the names in the secondary field, I'm thinking I need to delete one of the secondaryn fields since there are two and change the !FULLNAME! to SECONDARYN.